# command to list missing windows hotfixes

Tags: windows, hotfix

When I run "systeminfo" in Windows, it shows a list of hot fixes that are installed in my computer, in the form of KBxxxxxxx.
Is there a way (preferably command line) to know explicit what are the hot fixes that I am missing?

Comment: Specifically, I am looking for a solution that depends only native utility that is readily available on Windows (such as wmic) or Microsoft (such as Sysinternals), and not 3rd party solution such as Windows-Exploit-Suggester. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: The more generally applicable the better, possibly XP and onwards.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a way (preferably command line) to know what hot fixes are missing?

> I am looking for a solution that depends only native utility that is readily available on Windows (such as wmic) or Microsoft (such as Sysinternals)

Assuming you don't mind downloading scripts from the [Microsoft Technet Gallery](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/) then you can use the PowerShell script `Get-WindowsUpdates.ps1`:

> This script will get all available udpates for the computer it is run on. It will then optionally install those updates, provided they do not require user input.

[Download link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-WindowsUpdatesps1-7c82c1f4/file/70285/1/Get-WindowsUpdates.ps1)

...

> **Without any parameters the script will return the title of each update that
>       is currently available.**

---

> NAME
>
> ```
> C:\scripts\powershell\production\Get-WindowsUpdates.ps1
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> Get and optionally install Windows Updates
>
> SYNTAX
>
> ```
> C:\scripts\powershell\production\Get-WindowsUpdates.ps1 [-Install] [-EulaAccept] [<CommonParameters>]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> This script will get all available udpates for the computer it is run
>   on.
>
> It will then optionally install those updates, provided they do not
>   require
>       user input.
>
> This script was based off the original vbs that appeared on the MSDN
>   site.
>       Please see the Related Links section for the URL.
>
> Without any parameters the script will return the title of each update
>   that
>       is currently available.

Source [Get-WindowsUpdates.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-WindowsUpdatesps1-7c82c1f4)

Comment: I run like this, C:\Users\wei>powershell -noexit -executionpolicy
bypass "& 'C:\Users\wei\Get-WindowsUpdates.ps1'"

Comment: @wei What? No output all all?

Comment: @wei Try running as administrator

Comment: Oh, I need a solution that needs to be able to run without Administrator's right, only to list the updates, not to install them.

Comment: @wei Try commenting out lines 59 and line 180 which write the the event logs (they are only information messages).

Comment: Unfortunately this is severely outdated now, and have been superseded by others. Like [this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=Cmdlets%3A%22Get-WindowsUpdate%22).